# rmtp lavfi & image2 queue blocking

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

`[image2 @ 0x7fb9ffc105e0] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 1024)`

How to resolve this, **after adding lavfi** & raising the queue value to 1024 error still present....

`ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -framerate 1 -thread_queue_size 512 -i bg.png \
-f lavfi -thread_queue_size 512 -i "amovie=audio.m4a:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB" \
-vf "realtime" \
-f flv rtmp://server.dev:1935/live/mystream`

No errors **w/o lavfi**

`ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i bg.png \
-vf "realtime" \
-f flv rtmp://server.dev:1935/live/mystream`

Comment: Skip the queue for the image input. Also try skipping it for the audio as well. If you get a warning, insert a fifo before realtime, and maybe `-af afifo` as well.

Comment: Added both and error remains, what does `Thread message queue blocking` actually impact? I see no difference in CPU use or video quality.